# Tween.js repeat

Tags: javascript, tween.js, tweenjs

In tween.js is there a built in way to know when the tween restarts? Or perhaps a way of knowing which # repeat you're currently on?

```js
          var foo = {}// some object
          var bar = {}// some other object

          var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(foo, fooGroup);

          tween.to(bar, 8000)
            .interpolation(TWEEN.Interpolation.CatmullRom)
            .repeat(100)
            //.onRestart(()=>{ 
            // not a real method but it will be soon 
            // if someone doesn't have a better idea
            //})
            .onComplete(()=>{
              console.log('tween done');// only fires once when tween has
                                        // repeated 100 times (which is expected)

            })
            .onUpdate(()=>{
              // do some stuff where I'd like to
              // know if the tween just reset or not
            })
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut)
            .start()
```

Answer (score 1):

yes tween.js can emit an event on everyRepeat with .onRepeat(function).

You can increment a counter on everyRepeat to keep a trace of the repeat index too.

The tween documentation mention : [Tween doc](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/1f85d6e74491037653ddad2ee4193958f09928e2/docs/user_guide.md)

> onRepeat
> Executed whenever a tween has just finished one repetition and will begin another.
> The tweened object is passed in as the first parameter.

```js
var foo = {} // some object
var bar = {} // some other object
let rCount = 0
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(foo, fooGroup);

tween.to(bar, 8000)
    .interpolation(TWEEN.Interpolation.CatmullRom)
    .repeat(100)
    .onRepeat((info) => {
        // info display bar on repeat start
        rCount++
        // other stuff...
    })
    .onComplete(() => {
        console.log('tween done'); // only fires once when tween has
        // repeated 100 times (which is expected)

    })
    .onUpdate(() => {
        // do some stuff where I'd like to
        // know if the tween just reset or not
    })
    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut)
    .start()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `_repeat` attribute on the tween object that decrements with every call to `update`, so this more or less works:

```js
var cnt = 100 // or whatever the # of repeats is
tween.onUpdate(() => {
  if (tween._repeat !== cnt) {
    cnt = tween._repeat;
    console.log('restarting..');
  }
});
```